# Accessing child value of JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, linq

```
public static void apiCall2()
{
    WebClient c = new WebClient();
    var data = c.DownloadString(baseURL + endPoint + "?access_key=" + accessKey + "&currencies=TWD&source=USD&format=1");
    //Console.WriteLine(data);
    JObject api = JObject.Parse(data);

    string conversion = "";

    foreach (var result in api["quotes"])
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(result);
        conversion = (string)result["USDTWD"];
        System.Console.WriteLine(conversion);
    }
}
```

When ever I run this simple JSON API call code I receive an error of

> Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.

The USDTWD (the only section inside of [quotes] is supposed to call a double which returns the exchange rate from USD to TWD, and even trying to call it in as a string does not seem to help.

Comment: Can you give some response samples?

Comment: Here is the link to the JSON file it is calling. All I am trying to do is get the USDTWD as a double.   http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=88ac736de70eaf00263ab52afe0de9b0&currencies=TWD&source=USD&format=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `foreach (var result in api["quotes"])` you are looping over the child objects of the 'quotes' `JObject` one of which is the `JProperty` with property name 'USDTWD'.  You then put that `JProperty` in the `result` variable.  Then here:

```
conversion = (string)result["USDTWD"]
```

you are trying to access the `USDTWD` property of `result` but `result` does not have a `USDTWD` property because **it is** the `USDTWD` property.  Hence the exception.

If you just need the value of the `USDTWD` property you can replace your foreach loop with this:

```
conversion = api["quotes"]["USDTWD"].ToString();
```

Comment: Well, actually he can probably just use result directly if he wants to iterate over all?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik - He could use `result` directly.  If `quotes` had more than one property then using `result` in a foreach loop might make sense. Based on the example he provided, though, it looks like that is not the case.  I would forgo the loop entirely and just grab the single value directly.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way is:

Change: `JObject api = JObject.Parse(data);`
To:

```
dynamic api = JObject.Parse(data);
var quote = api.quotes.USDTWD;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion that might help you fix the issue by using a class with a structure rather than "raw" JObject. If you create a class like that:

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public bool Success {get;set;}
    ....

    public List<Quote> Quotes {get;set;}
}

public class QuoteModel
{
    public decimal USDTWD {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can convert to that object like that:

```
var response = api.ToObject<ResponseModel>();
```

I am not sure if this is acceptable for you (e.g. you might not have all the different quotes, or they are not all listed). But it is usually a more convenient way of working with responses than using JObject directly in my opinion.

P.S. Maybe you can even have a List as Quotes property to not hardcode it all, but I am not sure on how it is supported.